# Running a program via GDB until the program segfaults/crashes

Tags: gdb

I need to debug a program which segfaults at uneven intervals. The program has a `while(true)` loop.

While debugging via GDB, it stops and asks for the `Enter` key to be pressed to continue. However, I want the program to run until it crashes. How do I do that in GDB?

Answer (score 1):

Use `set height 0` or `set pagination off`. [Reference](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Screen-Size.html#Screen-Size)